# PHPMailer не отправляет файл

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

Реализую отправку zip файла на почту PHPMailer'ом, используя `smtp.gmail.com`. Zip который весит от 35мб как я понял не может отправиться ибо файлы более 35мб должны загружаться на Google Диск и распространяться ссылкой, как быть в такой ситуации? Файл более 35мб в моем случае это минимум.

Comment: Оставить файл на хостинге а отправить только ссылку? Или загрузить файл на GoogleDrive и оставить ссылку на него